# Constructing a string that does not include integer if it is 0 in Java?

Tags: java, string, math

Let's say that I have:

```
int hours = 0;
int minutes = 0;
int seconds = 5;
System.out.println("Simplified time: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":");
```

it will obviously print out:

```
Simplified time: 0:0:5:
```

Does anyone have any idea to make it print out like:

```
Simplified time: 5:
```

without using some if else statements? Of course if (hours>0) I would like it to print out the whole Print statement Like if (hours=3) I want it to print out:

```
Simplified time: 3:0:5:
```

Comment: How will you be able to tell if you had hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=5 from hours=5,minutes=0,seconds=0?

Comment: Any special reason for "without using some if else statements"?

Comment: No real reason for not using some if else statements I was just wondering if there was a good way. If not than thanks for the info!

Comment: You don't need the extra colon ( `:` ) in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to remove leading zeroes and `:` after them.

If that is the case you can apply `replaceAll(regex,replacement)` to `x:x:x:` part to remove 1 or 2 of `0:` placed at start (we don't want to remove last `0:`).

```
"Simplified time: " + (hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":").replaceAll("^(0:){1,2}", "");
```

`^(0:){1,2}` regex means

- `^` represents start of string (in our case start of `x:x:x:` since `replaceAll` is applied only to that part), it prevents matching `0:` in the middle of string if there is no `0:` before it,
- `0:` is literal,
- `(0:)` is *group* holding `0:` literal, we need it so we could apply quantifiers for that entire literal, not only single character
- `{1,2}` quantifier representing "once or twice" (to be more precise in range one till two, since its syntax represents repetition range `{nim,max}`)

Comment: @Orin2005 But I do. If hours > 0 then there will be no `0:` at start of `x:x:x:` so nothing will be replaced.

Comment: @SlinkyMation BTW, if you decide that you don't really need that last `:` after `seconds` then you can also replace `{1,2}` part with more common `+` which means *once or more*. I didn't use `+` before since I didn't want in case `0:0:0:` to match also last `0:`, but if that last `0` wouldn't have `:` after it then it can't be matched by `0:` pattern so it won't be replaced making `+` safe here.

Answer (score 3):

That is what `if-else` statements are for. But you could do some ternary operators too.

```
System.out.println( "Simplified time: " + ( hours > 0 ? hours + ":" : "" ) + (minutes > 0 || hours > 0 ? minutes + ":" : "" ) + seconds + ":" );
```

Although this looks like a jumbled mess and I would suggest using `if-else` for improved readability.

If you want to go this approach though, I would concatenate a String using Stringbuilder or the sorts before printing such as:

```
Stringbuilder sb = new Stringbuilder();
sb.append( hours > 0 ? hours + ":" : "");
sb.append( minutes > 0 || hours > 0 ? minutes + ":" : "");
sb.append( seconds );

System.out.println( sb.toString );
```

This just enhances the readability and as such would look cleaner than putting a lot of ternary expressions in the same line.

If you are wondering what Ternary operators are, think of it as a glorified `if-else` statement.

for example:

```
sb.append( hours > 0 ? hours + ":" : "" );
```

is the same as:

```
if( hours > 0 )
    sb.append( hours + ":" );
else
    sb.append( "" );
```